# PHP MapScript API Development for MapServer

Tags: web-mapping, mapserver, php, web

[PHP MapScript Tutorial](http://mapserver.org/mapscript/php/by_example.html#php-example)
I'd like to use the PHP MapScript API and am curious how others have successfully used it to produce a site that serves up remote sensing data.  I've got land surface temperatures, emissivities, and reflectances I'd like to share via a mapserver.  I've already installed mapserver on an apache webserver and have also installed the MapScript shared library.  What is a good development environment to use for PHP MapScript development?  Any example sites that use PHP MapScript people know of?  How useful is the MapScript API and how easy is it to use?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to answer to each question separately, starting from the development enviroment: I guess any IDE that supports php will work for PHP mapscript development. I can't suggest any because I don't use php, just google '[php ide](https://www.google.it/search?q=php%20ide&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)'.

As for example sites I should point you to the two most popular Open Source web applications built with PHP/mapscript:

1. [p.mapper](http://www.pmapper.net/index.shtml) : probably the best one, actively mantained and with the most comprehensive feature set
2. [cartoweb](http://www.cartoweb.org/) : outdated, still pretty good (for learning the api at least)

With regards to your last question I think that the Mapscript API is probably not the easiest to use, mostly because it's very powerful and documentation still has to catch up for some areas that have recently changed. Other than that I think an average developer should be able to be up and running within days and, if there are any problems, the mailing list and the #mapserver IRC channel are both active.

Comment: But would you suggest not using the MapScript API?  I like that it's powerful but not that it's hard to use.  I know there are other SDKs out there besides MapServer as well.  I'm looking at your suggested example sites now.